2014 UNCO Math Contest II problem

The March Hare invites $11$ guests to a tea party. He randomly assigns to each guest either tea or cake, but no guest receives both. The guests know that the March Hare always does this, but they never know which guests will receive tea and which will receive cake. The guests decide to play a game. Each one tries to guess who of all $11$ guests will get cake and who will get tea. If one guest has more correct guesses than all the others, that guest wins. When several guests tie for the most correct guesses, then the Dormouse selects one to be the winner by selecting at random one of the guessers who has tied


Suppose that instead of guessing randomly, Tweedledee always makes the guess opposite to Tweedledum’s guess. If Tweedledum guesses that a guest will have tea, then Tweedledee will guess cake. If all the other guests have guessed randomly, what is the probability that one or the other of Tweedledee and Tweedledum is the winner?

I tried out the above problem using symmetry arguments but have been unable to arrive at a solution. The solution link for the problem only has the answer, given to be $(\frac{1}{m+1}) \frac{2^{m+1}-1}{2^{m}}$ , where $m=9$ here.
Any help or hints on how to approach this will be appreciated.

The UNCO Mathematics Contest website contains many, if not all, solutions to past problems.  In your case, this pdf from 2013-2014 is the one you want. (go to the last two pages)

Thanks for providing the link for the solution.
